# Ember route model() error and model() data is not displayed in related hbs template

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

code:
https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/85d2b73b7f28903486e61cfa719ccdd1

you can play here
https://ember-twiddle.com/85d2b73b7f28903486e61cfa719ccdd1?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var companies = [{
      "name" : "Google",
      "headquarters": "Mountain View, California, United States of America",
      "revenue":"59825000000"
    },{
      "name" : "Facebook",
      "headquarters":"Menlo Park, California, United States of America",
      "revenue":"7870000000"
    },{
      "name" : "twitter",
      "revenue": "664000000",
      "headquarters":"San Francisco, California, United States of America"
    }];
    return companies;
  };
});
```

**getting the following error**

```
ember-twiddle-f01fea9….js:2 SyntaxError: routes/my-route.js: unknown: Unexpected token (17:3)
    }];
    return companies;
  };
});
    at t.default.raise (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.s.unexpected (vendor-9da9463….js:76)
    at t.s.expect (vendor-9da9463….js:76)
    at t.s.parseObj (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.s.parseExprAtom (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.parseExprAtom (vendor-9da9463….js:77)
    at t.s.parseExprSubscripts (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.s.parseMaybeUnary (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.s.parseExprOps (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
    at t.s.parseMaybeConditional (vendor-9da9463….js:75)
```

plus data from route.model() **is not displayed** in associated hbs template
[image]

#### what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

*my-route.hbs*

```
my-route
<hr size=1 />
{{input type="text" value=firstName disabled=nameDisabled size="40"}}

<table id="t01">
 <tr>
   <th>Company Name</th>
   <th>Headquarters</th>
   <th>revenue</th>
 </tr>
 {{#each model as |item|}}
 <tr>
  <td >{{item.name}}</td>
  <td class={{className}}>{{item.headquarters}}</td>
  <td>{{item.revenue}}</td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
</table>
<button {{action "toggleColor"}}> Change color </button>
```

I believe some of the old handlebars expressions were deprecated, such as `bind-attr`.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that line no 17 has a syntax error, there you got `};` to fix this error need to remove `;`
- `each` block syntax changed `{{#each model as |item|}}`
- Removed `bind-attr` that's deprecated one. you can use it direclty just like other property binding `class={{className}}`

[Twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/8a1199c6467face6f219196cb2b55639?openFiles=router.js%2C)

Comment: thanks  = that removed the error, but still the template is the same = empty while it's supposed to have a list of companie via #each calls in hbs. https://ember-twiddle.com/85d2b73b7f28903486e61cfa719ccdd1?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route